# Push notification not working when set APS Environment to development

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I use p8.

Please more information why we have to set APS Environment with production before that I set it with development it is working

[image]

Comment: for Appstore build APs enviornment should be producion, on the basis of this your SDK will know what enviornment of APS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does your server sends push requests to: Production or Sandbox?

Your app configuration should match with what the backend is doing.

Comment: It's production

Comment: If backend sends APNS requests to production url, then your app/build should be in production environment as well. The easiest way to do that is to make AppStore build and upload it to Testflight for testing.